# Django-Channels: another chatconsumer that is the same websocket

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

So I am making a project that use websockets, it works very well. I decided to include the websocket connection to another page, so I decided to add the other page in my routing.py, also I made another ChatConsumer for the other page, the problem is that I release that they are two different connections, how can I make my other chatconsumer the same as the other chatconsumer for this connection to be the same websocket connection?

here is my consumer.py:

```
import asyncio
import json 
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

from .models import Thread, ChatMessage

class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print("connected", event)

        other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
        me = self.scope['user']
        # print(other_user, me)
        thread_obj = await self.get_thread(me, other_user)
        self.thread_obj = thread_obj
        chat_room = f"thread_{thread_obj.id}"
        self.chat_room = chat_room
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            chat_room,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })
        # await asyncio.sleep(10)

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        # when a message is received from the websocket
        print("receive", event)

        front_text = event.get('text', None)
        if front_text is not None:
            loaded_dict_data = json.loads(front_text)
            msg =  loaded_dict_data.get('message')
            user = self.scope['user']
            username = 'default'
            if user.is_authenticated:
                username = user.username
            myResponse = {
                'message': msg,
                'username': username,
            }

            await self.create_chat_message(user, msg)

            # broadcast the message event to be send
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.chat_room,
                {
                    "type": "chat_message",
                    "text": json.dumps(myResponse)
                }
            )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        # sends the actual message
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event['text']
        })

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        # when the socket connects
        print("disconnected", event)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_thread(self, user, other_username):
        return Thread.objects.get_or_new(user, other_username)[0]

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_chat_message(self, me, msg):
        thread_obj = self.thread_obj
        return ChatMessage.objects.create(thread=thread_obj, user=me, message=msg)
```

maybe you will say "well why dont you use the chatconsumer in routing?", I cant use the chatconsumer, because it is giving this error

```
File "./consumers.py" in websocket_connect
other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
'username'
```

thank you for the help

Comment: Can you add the routing configuration you tried that resulted in the error? Using routing would probably be simpler

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple consumers accessible to the same websocket connection you need to look into using a `multiplexing` solution see: https://github.com/hishnash/channelsmultiplexer

Comment: I dont understand very well the channels multiplexing, and how can I add it?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your issue? do you have 2 browser  tabs open or do you want 2 different consumers for the same browser tab?